# Prevent App update in App code during runtime of it

Tags: android, google-play

Can I prevent the Auto-Update function of Android Google Play Store from App-Code, for example if I have a running navigation I don't want that the OS replace my App with an Update of it.

Comment: No, you can't. If the users triggers update from Play Store, there is no way to block this update. How can it be a problem?

Comment: Mobile is used in a car, connected to a powerbank or zigar poweradapter and using WLAN of the car, an App saving GPS Positions in background but as foregroundservice. I know it is theoretical but are you sure that Google detecting the the service as "App is running" and did'nt replace and restart my App ?

Comment: Yes, when you click install on Play Store, the OS actually replaces the current app APK. Once download is finished, install will start and erase the current APK.

Once you go back to your app, as the APK has changed, it will forces an app restart based on the latest APK.